# ModuleNotFoundError despite installing packages and selecting the right interprester in VSCode

Tags: python, installation, import, libraries, modulenotfounderror

I see a `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'xlwt'`

I created a virtual environment and installed the packages using the following commands:

```
py -3 -m venv .venv
.venv\scripts\activate
python -m pip install xlwt
```

This error is not specific to this module. Even matplotlib, seaborn, spacy and other libraries are resulting in the same issue.

I have also checked for the interpreter using the "Select Interpreter" command. It seems like the right interpreter is being used - the one I just created.

Typing `pip list` in the terminal also lists these libraries as expected.

Running the code (ctrl+Alt+N) is when I see the ModuleNotFoundError.

Any idea if I'm missing something here?

Comment: If you are using VSCode, try using F5 to run the code.

Comment: can you import the libraries in a python session launched from the terminal in VSCode?